# Error in Moodle Missing required parameter (id)

Tags: moodle

In one of the courses, an error occurs when trying to create a backup copy of the test: "Missing required parameter (id)".

The test was previously ported from moodle 1.9.9 to moodle version 3.11.6 and works great.

Why then it is not copied? What parameter is missing?

---

I turned on debug mode and error output, but I didn't see anything on the page.
I looked in the logs, but found nothing there (little experience).
I cleared all site caches through the Administration section.

Comment: This needs a bit more informations, but have you tried adding `?id=some_id` to the request you're trying to execute

Answer (score 0):

Is the debug level set to developer?

I can't see "Missing required parameter" as a language string in the core moodle code - is that the exact string?

If it isn't the exact string, can you update the question with the exact string.

If it is the exact string, then it might be a contributed / custom plugin

When you backup the course, in the backup settings, try selecting 1 activity/module at a time until the error occurs. Then you know which activity is displaying the error - can you update the question with the activity type/plugin name.

Comment: An error occurs when copying, for example, one test.

The error refers to this documentation:

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/error/moodle/missingparam